# How to get a PHP script to restart/rerun itself via PHP command

Tags: php

Say I start a PHP script via command line.

Is there a way that PHP can restart/rerun the script from the top via a command inside the PHP script?

```
<?php
if($something == 'yes')
{
 // restart/rerun whole PHP script
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you mean a loop?

Comment: Hi, no not a loop. I would like to force restart/rerun the entire script.

Comment: @Mr.Boon Put all these inside a function and call the function again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute a PHP script from another PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450696/execute-a-php-script-from-another-php-script)

Answer (score 0):

As told in comment you can send header.
or if you in the middle of page, you can add `<script>` tag with `window.location.reload()` there

Comment: Hi, this is a PHP only script, no HTML/JS. Only runs via cron in commandline

Comment: Then advice of @Mr.Boon. Script with variable `needReload = false` then all script in function. In case of success do nothing. If you need reload then `needReload = true` and return. In main script call function again in loop if `true`. But beware of endless cycle.