# file_get_content after executing php

Tags: php, file-get-contents, mpdf

I am trying to make a pdf file with mpdf.

```php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['mode' => 'utf-8', 'format' => 'A4-L']);
$mpdf->use_kwt = true;
$html = file_get_contents('template.php');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
```

the file that I am trying to get converted to a pdf has several variables declared and used in the template itself. The issue that I am encountering is that when you use file_get_contents it just gets the file without executing it at all. Is there a way to get the content only after it is executed and everything is parsed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8450735/5962966

Comment: I disagree with this closing of my question. I could not find the answer in the topic. If you include something it is added to your page and not added as content to be used by mpdf.